# unable to list accounts in web3.py via RPC

Tags: web3.py, rpc

I built a private chain on my computer using `geth` and I want to interact with it using `web3.py`. But there was something wrong.

I started the private chain(*containing only one node*) with the command

```
$ geth --datadir datadir --rpc --rpcport 8545 --port 30301 --ipcpath /tmp/geth.ipc --rpccorsdomain '*' --unlock 0
```

Having started the chain, I was able to use the environment in remix IDE via RPC.
Then I followed the [docs](http://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/providers.html) of web3.py and wrote some simple code:

```
from web3 import Web3, HTTPProvider
w3 = Web3(HTTPProvider('http://localhost:8545'))
print(w3.eth.blockNumber)
print(w3.personal.listAccounts)
```

What upset me was that the `w3.eth.blockNumber` worked just fine but the `listAccounts` didn't.
Here is a picture of the error message :
[image: via RPC]

Some info:
**OS**: ubuntu16.04
**geth**: 1.8.2
**web3.py**: 3.16.5

A noobie here, please help T_T. I googled this but didn't find similar problems (maybe this is too simple?).

Comment: i'm not familiar with the python framework, but my instinct says to try `w3.eth.accounts` to fetch accounts

Comment: The personal API can be abused pretty easily over HTTP, so it is typically disabled by default over HTTP. Check `geth --help` for enabling `personal` api's over HTTP (but please don't do this on mainnet, with real assets at stake).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the comments @carver and @Chris.

Just as carver said in the comments, the problem is that personal api is not enabled by default and I didn't add the `--rpcapi` flag.

### solution

option 1 : start geth with the flag `--rpcapi personal,web3,eth` and any other flags necessary.

option 2 : use the `eth.accounts`, which is enabled by default.

Comment: i already had `--rpcapi personal,web3,eth` flag, but still can't access through `personal` but `eth` works, is it an error or wrong api instruction from web3py?